# BigUint and "cannot move out of borrowed content" error

Tags: rust

I tried to follow the iterator approach described in [Rust by Example's Iterator section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/trait/iter.html) with [`BigUint`](https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint):

```
extern crate num_bigint;

use num_bigint::{BigUint, ToBigUint};

struct FibState {
    a: BigUint,
    b: BigUint,
}

impl Iterator for FibState {
    type Item = BigUint;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<BigUint> {
        let b_n = self.a + self.b;
        self.a = self.b;
        self.b = b_n;
        Some(self.a)
    }
}

fn fibs_0() -> FibState {
    FibState {
        a: 0.to_biguint().unwrap(),
        b: 1.to_biguint().unwrap(),
    }
}

fn fib2(n: usize) -> BigUint {
    if n < 2 {
        n.to_biguint().unwrap()
    } else {
        fibs_0().skip(n - 1).next().unwrap()
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Fib1(300) = {}", fib2(300));
}
```

The above code does not compile:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:13:19
   |
13 |         let b_n = self.a + self.b;
   |                   ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:13:28
   |
13 |         let b_n = self.a + self.b;
   |                            ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:14:18
   |
14 |         self.a = self.b;
   |                  ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:16:14
   |
16 |         Some(self.a)
   |              ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I am not sure if it is due to the `BigUint` type is not primitive thus it does not have the `Copy` trait. How can I modify the iterator to make it works with the `FibState` struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<BigUint> {
    let b_next = &self.a + &self.b; 
    let b_prev = std::mem::replace(&mut self.b, b_next);
    self.a = b_prev;
    Some(self.a.clone())
}
```

1. `BigUint` does not implement `Copy`, but the [`Add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html) trait takes both arguments by value. `BigUint` implements `Add` for references as well, so you can take references of the values instead.
2. We would like to replace the current value of `b` with the next value of `b`, but we need to keep the old value. We can use [`mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) for that.
3. Assigning the old `b` value to `a` is straightforward.
4. Now we wish to return the value in `a`, so we need to [`clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) the entire value.

> `BigUint` type is not primitive thus it does not have the `Copy` trait

Something being a primitive and something implementing the `Copy` trait have nothing to do with each other. User types can implement `Copy` and some primitives do not implement `Copy`.

See also:

- [How to swap two variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31798737/155423)
- [How do I implement the Add trait for a reference to a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28005134/155423)
- [Operator overloading by value results in use of moved value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27856991/155423)