# Could Rust take an immutable reference of a value automatically?

Tags: rust

I have a struct with a couple of operators implemented for it:

```rust
use std::ops;

/// Vector of 3 floats
#[derive(Debug, Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Vec3 {
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub z: f32,
}

/// Add operator
impl ops::Add<&Vec3> for &Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;

    #[inline(always)]
    fn add(self, rhs: &Vec3) -> Self::Output {
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x + rhs.x,
            y: self.y + rhs.y,
            z: self.z + rhs.z,
        }
    }
}

/// Subtract operator
impl ops::Sub<&Vec3> for &Vec3 {
    type Output = Vec3;

    #[inline(always)]
    fn sub(self, rhs: &Vec3) -> Self::Output {
        Vec3 {
            x: self.x - rhs.x,
            y: self.y - rhs.y,
            z: self.z - rhs.z,
        }
    }
}

/// Scalar multiplication operator
impl ops::Mul<&Vec3> for f32 {
    type Output = Vec3;

    #[inline(always)]
    fn mul(self, rhs: &Vec3) -> Self::Output {
        Vec3 {
            x: self * rhs.x,
            y: self * rhs.y,
            z: self * rhs.z,
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use the operators:

```rust
let a = Vec3 { x: 0.0, y: 0.5, z: 1.0 };
let b = Vec3 { x: 1.0, y: 0.5, z: 0.0 };
let c = Vec3 { x: 1.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0 };
let d = Vec3 { x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 1.0 };
let result = 2.0 * (a + b) - 3.0 * (c - d);
```

This code will not compile because the operators are implemented for `&Vec3`, not for `Vec3`. To fix the issue, the last line would have to look like this:

```rust
let result = &(2.0 * &(&a + &b)) - &(3.0 * &(&c - &d));
```

Which doesn't look that nice anymore.

I understand that I could implement the operators for `Vec3` to avoid that problem, but what if I still want to use immutable references to these vectors on the stack? Is there perhaps a way to give Rust some hint that if I write `a + b` and there is no operator for `Vec3 + Vec3`, that it could try and look for a `&Vec3 + &Vec3` operator instead, and if found, take the immutable references for both arguments automatically?

Comment: alternatively, you could have a,b,c,d as references to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, that's true. The intermediate results of the `+`/`-`/`*` operations would still be `Vec3`s, though, so the line would look like `let result = &(2.0 * &(a_ref + b_ref)) - &(3.0 * &(c_ref - d_ref));`

Comment: It is common to implement binary operators for both references and owned values, e.g. for `Vec3 + Vec3`, `&Vec3 + Vec3`, `Vec3 + &Vec3` and `&Vec3 + &Vec3`. This way, all intermediate results can be passed by value – it's fine to move them anyway. Together with making your variables references to begin with, this allows you to write the expression exactly in the form you want.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no way of automatically taking a reference when adding two values.

You could write your own macro that does this, I suppose. In usage, it would look like:

```
thing!{ a + b }
// expands to
(&a + &b)
```

I'd expect that this macro would quickly become tiresome to write.

See also:

- [Allow autoderef and autoref in operators — RFC #2147](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2147)
- [Tracking issue: Allow autoderef and autoref in operators (experiment) #44762](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44762)
- [Does println! borrow or own the variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30450399/155423)
- [How to implement idiomatic operator overloading for values and references in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38811387/155423)
- [Operator overloading by value results in use of moved value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27856991/155423)
- [How can I implement an operator like Add for a reference type so that I can add more than two values at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45174458/155423)